# How to make a shallow copy of NSManagedObject when objects' contexts differ?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am implementing "duplicate" functionality in my iOS application. I'm using the following workflow:

1. present a list of managed objects in initial context in root view controller
2. when user taps on a row, create a new context pass it to "detail" view controller with duplicated managed object (`[[DetailController alloc] initWithObject:clonedObject inContext:newContext]`).

However I am struggling with the concept of reassigning relations from source object to the cloned one since their managed object contexts differ. What would be correct approach to this:

1. Should I just reassign the pointer value and do not bother about MOC or...
2. I should refetch the values in new context depending on their unique identifiers?
3. Any other option I did not think of?

P.S. Contexts are using same persistent store coordinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed object IDs are thread safe. As such, you can pass a managed object ID to the MOC in your view controller, retrieve that object via existingObjectWithID:error, then perform the duplication in that context. This way, the objects never cross MOC boundaries.

Comment: Any particular reason not to user `objectWithID:`?

Comment: ObjectWithID always returns an object, even if that object is a fault. See http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/safely-fetching-nsmanagedobject-by-uri.html